# How to change specific elements style in storybook?

Tags: storybook

In my case I just want to change the default  default color, take as example the default home section:

```
We recommend building UIs with a [**component-driven**](https://componentdriven.org)
```

That leads to:
[image]
I'd like to change that blue to, say, red.

I saw that the a class has the following themes:

```
class="sbdocs sbdocs-a css-19nbuh3"
```

So, I created a .storybook/manager-head.html and inside I wrote:

```
<style>
    .sbdocs-a {
    color: red;
  }
```

But I see no changes! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: pretty sure its just a typo but your `style` tag isn't closed

Comment: yes it's closed I just pasted wrong

Answer (score 4):

You can do this two ways but all in `.storybook/preview.js`.

#### Altering the docs theme:

```js
export const parameters = {
  ...
  docs: {
    theme: {
      colorSecondary: 'red',
    },
  },
  ...
};
```

> This have the side effect to cause other unwanted components to change their color, as this color is not used only for links.

#### Provide your own `<a>` component to docs [best solution]:

```
export const parameters = {
  ...
  docs: {
    components: {
      a: ({children, ...args}) => <a style={{color: 'red'}} {...args}>{children}</a>
    },
  },
  ...
};
```

This is the best way i found to style docs components.

also token name used for `a` can be found in [storybook sources](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/lib/components/src/typography/DocumentFormatting.tsx#L86-L105)

See [theming docs page](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/theming#theming-docs) for a full theme example.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work: the <a> is still blue...

Comment: for which `<a>` exactly do you want the color to change? please provide more information or a screenshot otherwise i cannot tell you which theme token to override

Comment: Thanks for your help, I updated the post with the information

Comment: Just found the exact token name and an other way to do this, i've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

you can create a file, let's say main.js and add

```
.sbdocs-a {
   color: red;
 }
```

and you need to add the path to your styles in preview.js folder storybook

```
import "./main.css:
```